# Contiguous dates joining 2 tables Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

Im desperately seeking a bit of help from all the Oracle SQL Guru's and Superheroes out here. Any advice and or assistance would be highly appreciated.

I have 2 tables Tab_A and Tab_B

**Table DDL's**

```
create table tab_A  
(item       varchar2(20),
 dest       varchar2(20),
 eff        date,
 disc       date,
 qty        number);
 
create table tab_B
(item       varchar2(20),
 source     varchar2(20),
 dest       varchar2(20),
 eff        date,
 disc       date);
 
 insert into tab_a values('item1','dest1','01 July 2022','31 July 2022',20);
 insert into tab_a values('item1','dest1','31 July 2022','15 Aug 2022',30);
 insert into tab_a values('item1','dest1','15 Aug 2022','15 Sep 2022',40);
 insert into tab_a values('item1','dest1','15 Sep 2022','15 Jan 2023',20);
 
 insert into tab_b values('item1-PS1','source1','dest1','01 July 2022','5 August 2022');
 insert into tab_b values('item1-PS2','source2','dest1','5 Aug 2022','10 Oct 2022');
 insert into tab_b values('item1-PS3','source3','dest1','10 October 2022','1 Feb 2023');
```

Table A -- & -- Table B

[image: Table A]      [image: Table B]

**Context**

Tab_A is linked to tab_b by item and dest. The Items are the same, however in Tab_B the item with "-PS1,-PS2 or -PS3" refers to the items packaging size but still the same item.

**Required**

I need to combine both tables into 1 new table with contiguous EFF and DISC dates Output below.

I need to use the eff and disc dates on table A to determine how long that item is active for that QTY. If Table B EFF and DISC dates are greater than table A dates then Table B item is the value to be used for that row. The moment the Table A EFF and DISC window is greater than table B DISC date then that record in Table A should end with the same DISC date and start a new row with the New Item from Table B with new EFF DATE and so forth. the output example will makes more sense.

Output of the data would look like this based on the 2 tables provided and with new contiguous **EFF** and **DISC** dates.

[image: Final_output]

Answer (score 0):

A join can find the matching rows. For example:

```
select b.item, b.dest,
  greatest(a.eff, b.eff) as eff,
  least(a.disc, b.disc) as disc,
  a.qty
from tab_a a
join tab_b b on b.dest = a.dest 
 and b.item like a.item || '%'
 and a.disc >= b.eff and a.eff <= b.disc
```

Result:

```
 ITEM       DEST   EFF        DISC       QTY 
 ---------- ------ ---------- ---------- --- 
 item1-PS1  dest1  01-JUL-22  31-JUL-22  20  
 item1-PS1  dest1  31-JUL-22  05-AUG-22  30  
 item1-PS2  dest1  05-AUG-22  15-AUG-22  30  
 item1-PS2  dest1  15-AUG-22  15-SEP-22  40  
 item1-PS2  dest1  15-SEP-22  10-OCT-22  20  
 item1-PS3  dest1  10-OCT-22  15-JAN-23  20
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=39547b56fe10a423984f1550e6fd7759).